# Use Regex in a 'CheckConstraint' from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Considering the example below, how can I make the constraint work according to the given regex?

In this case, I am using SQLAlchemy inside a Flask application.

```
class user(db.Model):
    iduser = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=True)
    CheckConstraint("REGEXP_LIKE(email,'^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\.[a-zA-Z]{2})$')", name='emailcheck')
```

(I am not 100% sure about the syntax in the last line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CHECK` constraints need to be in the table itself, using `__table_args__`:

```
class user(db.Model):
    ...
    __table_args__ = (CheckConstraint("regexp_like(email, ...)", name=...),)
```

You can also put it outside of the class, but SQLAlchemy needs to know what table it's for, so you'll need to write the constraint as an expression instead of a string:

```
class user(db.Model):
    ...

CheckConstraint(func.regexp_like(user.email, ...), name=...)
```

Comment: I didn't work. It had no effect on the database at all.
I should note that I am not exactly sure about this syntax where "regexp_like(email, ...)" is all sent as a string... I used it as an example.

Comment: @RafaelAuyer What do you mean it had no effect? How are you verifying it has no effect?

Comment: I figured that I needed to recreate the table for it to take effect.

Comment: Does this not work with an existing table?

Comment: This didn't work for me with an existing table - i added the check constraint as above, regenerated migrations, then viewed table in dbeaver and no constraints were added (though comments were updated). Using postgres 14, alembic, sqlalchemy.

Comment: Not sure if this affects the answer above: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4463